# export in SOAP complete properties of entity reference

Tags: asp.net, linq, web-services, entity-framework, soap

why in SOAP, linq not export the complete properties of entity References, in this example only export EntityKeyMember of ImagesReference and no the other properties of Images entity

```
<images_likes>
<EntityKey>
    <EntitySetName>Images_Likes</EntitySetName>
    <EntityContainerName>WiredinEntities</EntityContainerName>
    <EntityKeyValues>
        <EntityKeyMember>
        <Key>LikeId</Key>
        <Value xsi:type="xsd:int">96</Value>
        </EntityKeyMember>
    </EntityKeyValues>
</EntityKey>
<LikeId>96</LikeId>
<Date>2012-07-27T09:00:35.697</Date>
<ImagesReference>
    <EntityKey>
        <EntitySetName>Images</EntitySetName>
        <EntityContainerName>WiredinEntities</EntityContainerName>
        <EntityKeyValues>
            <EntityKeyMember>
            <Key>ImageId</Key>
            <Value xsi:type="xsd:int">26</Value>
            </EntityKeyMember>
        </EntityKeyValues>
    </EntityKey>
</ImagesReference>
```

```
public static List<Images_Likes> GetLikes(int ImageId)
{
    using (WiredinEntities context = new WiredinEntities("name=WiredinEntities"))
    {
        var items = from item in context.Images_Likes.Include("Images")
                    where item.Images.ImageId == ImageId
                    select item;


        return items.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that produced this. There's no way for us to guess what's wrong. Also, tell us what you expected to see.

Comment: So what did you expect to see? Isn't this all of the properties of the `Images_Likes` class?

Comment: ImagesReference have "Photo" property and only show EntityKeyMember

Comment: Maybe the `Photo` property is not serializable? You still should show us the code.

Comment: ---Images entity----

ImageId int
Photo nvarchar(100)
Date datetime
UserName nvarchar(100)

---Images_Likes entity---

LikeId int
ImageId int
Date datetime 
UserName nvarchar(256)